# Jmeter:I am getting error while recording script

Tags: testing, jmeter

I am getting this error while i am trying to record the script through browser,anyone give me a solution...
"Could not create script recording proxy-port in use.Choose another port.:Already used in JVM_Bind"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that you have something else listening port `8080` which is default for JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder)

You can check what application is bound to that port via `netstat` or `lsof` commands.

- For Windows - `netstat -nao | Find "8080"`
- For Linux - `netstat -naop | grep -w 8080`
- For Mac - `lsof -n -i4TCP:8080 | grep LISTEN`

and stop it.

Alternatively:

1. Change "Port" under "Global Settings" of your HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder to be something different. Don't forget to adjust your browser proxy settings accordingly.
2. Use [Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) which record JMeter test scripts right from browser and capable of exporting them to JMeter .jmx files. In that case you won't have to worry about proxies, ports, certificates, cookies, etc.